# Units in a number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{229}]$ and let $z\in K$ be an element of norm $\pm3$. Prove that after possibly multiplying $z$ by a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_{K}^{\times}$ we may assume that $u^{-1/2}\leq z\leq u^{1/2}$ where $u$ is a fundamental unit.

So far I have shown that $u=7+\frac{1+\sqrt{229}}{2}$ is a fundamental unit and I have no idea what to do now.

Comment: *Not* a duplicate, but coincidentally relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2040999/easiest-way-to-show-x2-229y2-12-has-no-solutions-in-integers

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're too focused on the details of the problem that you're missing the obvious. Try this exercise:

> Let $x$ and $y$ be positive real numbers. Prove there exists an integer $n$ such that $x^{-1/2} \leq x^n y \leq x^{1/2}$

Comment: Ok it is obvious because "*after possibly multiplying $z$ by a unit*". So  this exercice is a nonsense ? (norm $\pm 3$)

Comment: @user1952009: Not nonsense, just very simple. It certainly seems *peculiar* out of context, though. I imagine, *in context* it makes sense as an exercise, e.g. as part (a) of a multi-part problem where this assumption needs to be made, so they ask you to show you can do so. Or, it could be an exercise in making sure you can still apply prior knowledge in the context of the new material.

Comment: @Hurkyl This is part of a multi part problem which goes on to show that no integral ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_{K}$ of norm $3$ is principal, and then to find integer solutions to $x^2+xy+y^2=57$.

Comment: @pilgrim For what it's worth, $$N\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{229}}{2}\right) = -57.$$

Answer (score 2):

*I* think that some basic facts about units have not been properly explained to you, and that's after I read some comments giving a little more of the context.

I would like to use $\eta$ (Greek lowercase eta) to represent *the* fundamental unit, and $u$ to represent arbitrary units in the relevant domain, in this case $\mathcal O_{\mathbb Q(\sqrt{229})}$. If $u > 1$ and no smaller $u$ satisfies this strict inequality, then $u = \eta$. Yeah, I know, that's kind of the definition of the fundamental unit.

The fundamental unit is important because $\eta^n$ and $-(\eta^n)$, in which you iterate $n$ through all the integers of $\mathbb Z$, gives all the units of the domain. In particular, note that $\eta^0 = 1$, $-(\eta^0) = -1$ and $-\eta < -1$. So we have $-\eta < -1 < 1 < \eta$.

Also, even though $\lfloor | \eta^n | \rfloor$ can be quite large, we nevertheless have $N(\eta^n) = \pm 1$. So those are the basic facts to keep in mind here.

Now, you're looking to place $zu$ in a smaller range than between $-\eta$ and $\eta$, namely, $$\frac{1}{\sqrt \eta} < zu < \sqrt \eta.$$ That's roughly between 0.25762953 and 3.8815426, for this particular exercise in $\mathcal O_{\mathbb Q(\sqrt{229})}$.

No number $z$ exists in this domain having a norm of 3 or $-3$, as Gerry Myerson explains in his answer to this question: [Easiest way to show $x^2 - 229y^2 = 12$ has no solutions in integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2040999/easiest-way-to-show-x2-229y2-12-has-no-solutions-in-integers?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But if such a number $z$ existed, you could place $zu$ in the desired range by simple trial and error. If $zu$ is too large, try a smaller unit. And if it's too small, try a larger unit, secure in the knowledge that $N(zu) = \pm 3$ regardless.

In order to give a concrete example, let's say that instead of $N(zu) = \pm 3$ you're looking for $N(zu) = -509$. Then we can do $$z = \frac{5}{2} + \frac{3 \sqrt{229}}{2} = 1 + \frac{3 + 3 \sqrt{229}}{2} \approx 25.1991189.$$ Clearly $z \eta$ will be too large, and we needn't bother with $z \eta^0$. But $z \eta^{-1} = 153 - 10 \sqrt{229} \approx 1.67254$, putting $zu$ in the desired range.